# Universal covering space of a Zariski open subset of projective space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-geometry, analytic-geometry, covering-spaces

Let $U$ be a Zariski open subset of $\mathbb P^n_{\mathbb C}$. Assume $U$ is the complement of some divisors.

Have the possible universal covering spaces of $U$ been classified?

Do we know when the universal covering space is a bounded symmetric domain?